# Adding indexes to SQLAlchemy models after table creation

Tags: python, indexing, sqlalchemy

I have a flask-sqlalchemy model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'targets'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
url = db.Column(db.String(2048))
```

The table has already been created, and is in use. I want to create an index on the url attribute, so I pass index=True to it:

```
url = db.Column(db.String(2048), index=True)
```

How can I make this index take effect, without deleting and recreating the table?

Answer (score 52):

Given the model class from the original question.

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'targets'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(2048))
```

You cannot just add `index=True` because even if you called `db.Model.metadata.create_all()` the index will not be created on an already created table.

Instead, you need to create an independent `Index` object, and then create it. It will look something like this:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'targets'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(2048))

mymodel_url_index = Index('mymodel_url_idx', MyModel.url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mymodel_url_index.create(bind=engine)
```

Now where `engine` comes from will be up to your sqlalchemy configuration, but this code should convey the gist of what needs to happen.

Comment: @PascalVKooten The name of the index: 'mymodel_url_idx' (in this case), can be set to any value but must be globally unique within the database.

Comment: When is `mymodel_url_index.create(bind=engine)` supposed to be executed? Does this change if I use alembic?

Comment: @learn2day `mymodel_url_index.create(bind=engine)` can be executed at any time, but should only be executed once. Running that line will create the index. I can't comment on alembic, because I don't know how it works, but I would expect a migrations utility to create indexes for you.

Comment: Can I use the index created by this method in [with_hint()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_hint)? And if yes, which syntax should I use?

Answer (score 40):

Since the question was asked, support has been added for this.

Now you can just add `index=True` to an existing column, and auto-generate the migration.

Checked on the following package versions:

```
alembic==1.0.10
SQLAlchemy==1.3.4
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.34.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2
```

Comment: I'm really happy to see this. I've tried searching for reference to this feature in the relevant libraries just now, but wasn't able to find any reference to it. I think it'd be really helpful if I/you/someone could dig up a link to the docs or changelog which references this feature and include it here.

Comment: If someone is looking to resource backing this, here are the docs for the index API. In the second example it shows that you can do this `Column("name", String(50), index=True)`

Comment: will this create the index automatically when you **migrate** without dropping the original table?

Comment: @pcko1 yes. You can verify that by looking at the commands in your generated migration file. You should always check auto-generated migration files before applying them.

Comment: verifying that it works, nice!

Answer (score 3):

**Please note that this is incorrect and over-complicated answer**

The right way is to use `index.create` as it was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16736472/1296661).

---

First of all make sure that you have latest snapshot of your database and is able to restore database from this snapshot.

For medium and large size projects (the ones that you might need to support several versions at the same time and are installed on multiple environments) there is special procedure which is part of database management lifecycle called "database migration". DB migrations includes changes to existing schema. SQLAlchemy doesn't support migration out of the box.

There are two SQLAlchemy compatible database migration tools available:

- [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/)
- [SQLAlchemy-Migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/)

See more information and links to these tools in SQLAlchemy documentation page: [Altering Schemas through Migrations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#altering-schemas-through-migrations).

But if your are working on small project I would suggest to manually run ALTER TABLE DDL query from the database command line utility or through connection.execute() in python script.

In the production application I'm working at right now, we support only one latest version of application. For every database schema change we do the following steps:

- make a snapshot of the production database
- load this snapshot on development environment
- update sqlalchemy data model module
- prepare and run alter table query and save this query for later
- make other related changes to the code
- run tests on dev environment
- deploy latest version of the code to production
- do alter table on production

Also I'm using the following trick for generating create table/index queries:
I point my application to brand new database, enable logging of sqlalchemy queries and run `metadata.create_all()` - so in logs (or STDOUT) I see create query generated by sqlalchemy

Depending on the database system you are using index creation query will be little different.
Generic query would look like this:

```
create index targets_i on targets(url);
```

Comment: sorry, this answer is wrong.  ALTER TABLE is not used for indexes.  SQLAlchemy supports "CREATE INDEX" very directly using `Index.create()`, as well as with the `CreateIndex` DDL construct for more elaborate scripting situations.  There's no need to grab the "create_all()" output or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for point out. I'm agree - I described how to implement and support approach asked in question. And completely forgot about easy and quick `index.create`.

Answer (score 2):

Call `create()` on the Index:

```
index.create()
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Index.create

Comment: This answer gives no idea from where to get this index object from the code in the original question. Crawling through the docs to find this is painstaking, and honestly barely helpful since they don't touch on using the declarative api (which is being used in the original question). For anyone else as confused as I, and not wanting to crawl docs and source code, see my below answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must be clear about two phases:

1. Your ORM: How your data model looks like
2. Your migration progress: Convert your Data model in design to DB table

Add `index=True` is updating your designed ORM only. You should check your migration progress - how they create your DB table based on your ORM. You did not mention migrations so I think you forgot them.

I recommend trying to manage your migration flow actively - know about [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/) and how it works for example.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if this conforms to best practices but I found `Alembic` would notify me of Indexes in the `__table_args__` but not actually make them for me during migrations. I made this small script that can generate new indexes found in the `__table_args__` property. It makes use of `Index.create()` as mentioned above, but will generate new indexes if they do not exist.

```
def create_indexes(db, drop_index=False):
    """
    Creates all indexes on models in project if they do not exists already. Assumes all models
    inherit from RequiredFields class, otherwise will need to adjust search for subclasses. If the index
    exists SQLAlchemy throws an error and we assume everything is ok. 
    :param db: The app db object, acts as the engine param for the Index.create()
    :param drop_index: specifies whether the indexes should be dropped or created
    :return:
    """
    from application.base_models import RequiredFields
    from sqlalchemy import Index
    from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError
    for klass in RequiredFields.__subclasses__():
        if hasattr(klass, '__table_args__'):
            for item in getattr(klass, '__table_args__'):
                if isinstance(item, Index):
                    try:
                        if not drop_index:
                            item.create(db.engine)
                        else:
                            item.drop(db.engine)
                    except ProgrammingError:  # If index exists, creation fails on error
                        pass
    return
```

Here is a sample class showing the indexes.

```
class MyModel(RequiredFields):

    __table_args__ = (
         db.Index( ... ),
         db.Index( ... ),
    )
```

Answer (score -14):

Use flask-migrate.It's cool.
After you add the index,just use this command:

```
python manage.py db migrate
```

Everything works fine