# pandas create database with index

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an sqlite database with pandas.

I am able to save the data with:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine                                                                                                                                                                               
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker                                                                                                                                                                            
engine = create_engine(path, echo=False)                                                                                                                                                                           
df_flows.to_sql('flows', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, index_label='First')
```

and I can read it back with

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM flows WHERE First>1504101810 AND First<1504105409", engine)
```

The data is on disk but I think the indexing is not working properly as:

```
In [22]: from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection                                                                                                                                                                  

In [23]: insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)                                                                                                                                                           

In [24]: insp.get_indexes('flows')                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[24]: []
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1) Why the column `First` does not appear with `insp.get_indexes('flows')`

2) How can I add 1 or more indexes to the database that I have created.

EDIT:

This is the structure of the data frame

```
In [25]: df_flows.dtypes                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[25]:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Protocol        object                                                                                                                                                                                      
Src             object                                                                                                                                                                                      
SrcPort        float64                                                                                                                                                                                      
Dst             object                                                                                                                                                                                      
DstPort        float64                                                                                                                                                                                      
Group ID         int64                                                                                                                                                                                      
Port            object                                                                                                                                                                                      
VPort            int64                                                                                                                                                                                      
IP TOS          object                                                                                                                                                                                      
VLAN ID        float64                                                                                                                                                                                      
VLAN Pri       float64                                                                                                                                                                                      
MPLS Exp       float64                                                                                                                                                                                      
Application     object                                                                                                                                                                                      
Packets          int64                                                                                                                                                                                      
Messages         int64                                                                                                                                                                                      
Bytes            int64                                                                                                                                                                                      
First            int64                                                                                                                                                                                      
Last             int64                                                                                                                                                                                      
SrcSubnet       object                                                                                                                                                                                      
DstSubnet       object                                                                                                                                                                                      
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the structure of your dataframe, so it is difficult to answer your question.  However, given your inputs, I can make some inferences.

When you save your database to sql, you set `index=False`.  This means that any index on your dataframe is not saved as a column in the database.  You then go on to assign an index label which will have no affect given that you set index to False.  This parameter used if you want to rename your existing index name.

> index : boolean, default True
>       Write DataFrame index as a column.
>
> index_label : string or sequence, default None
>       Column label for index column(s). If None is given (default) and
>       `index` is True, then the index names are used.
>       A sequence should be given if the DataFrame uses MultiIndex.

An database index would have to be created through the database, not pandas.

Comment: so you are saying that if `index_label` is not `None` then index must be set to True and it is automatically replaced with the specified column name?

Comment: No. I am saying `index_label` is ignored if `index=False`. If `index=True` (the default value), it will write the index as a column using its name.  You can use another name, however, using the `index_label` parameter.

Comment: ok but what if I want to add indices later of if I want to index by mulitple columns?

Comment: My aim is to have a database where I can quickly search on the variables `First` and `Src` ( the first one is numeric and the second one is string)

Comment: The index in a pandas dataframe has nothing to do with the database index.  You would need to build the index yourself using your database package.  The `index` parameter is merely asking if you want to write the dataframe index as columns in the database (this wouldn't be needed, for example, if the index is just the ordered range, e.g. 0, 1, 2, ... n).

Comment: ok now I understand. In point 2 of my question I was asking how to create the database index. I'm using `SQLAlchemy` but I can not find a tutorial to add an index to a database created with pandas

Comment: The fact that the table was created with pandas has no impact.  It is just a table.  Proceed with your SqlAlchemy tutorial on index creation as normal. Perhaps this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419299/adding-indexes-to-sqlalchemy-models-after-table-creation/16736472#16736472

Comment: From the answer in the link I do not understand how to add the index. Can you explain me how to do it in this specific case?

Comment: Sounds like a new question. "Create a database index using SqlAlchemy Core".